# PostgreSQL: how do build a table with an ever-increasing daily total?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming this data:

```
ID    DATE
44    2019-12-31
45    2020-01-01
46    2020-01-01
47    2020-01-02
48    2020-01-03
48    2020-01-03
48    2020-01-03
```

How do I make a query that returns something like this?

```
TOTAL     DATE
2         2020-01-01
3         2020-01-02
6         2020-01-03
```

I want all entries after a certain data, but with a counter that starts with the number of entries on the first day, then for every day, it adds the number of entries on that day. I want to plot them on a chart that shows the speed of the growth.

Is this possible? I'm on PostgreSQL 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select date,
       count(*) as count_on_date,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(date)) as running_count
from t
where date >= '2020-01-01'
group by date
order by date;
```

If you wanted a count going back in time, then you would use:

```
select greatest(date, '2020-01-01'::date) as date
       count(*) as count_on_date,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(date)) as running_count
from t
group by greatest(date, '2020-01-01'::date)
order by greatest(date, '2020-01-01'::date);
```